# Increment dictionary in a loop:

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I need to count how many times a given number os text patterns appears in a log file and store this in a dictionary.

My problem is that my code is counting all entries of the file to every kind of text pattern.

The log file looks like this:

What i doing wrong?

```
>Feb  1 00:00:02 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 >PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX LEN=40 TOS=0x00 >PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=12973 PROTO=TCP SPT=220 DPT=6129 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 >SYN URGP=0  
>Feb  1 00:00:02 bridge kernel: INBOUND TCP: IN=br0 PHYSIN=eth0 OUT=br0 >PHYSOUT=eth1 SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX DST=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX LEN=40 TOS=0x00 >PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=27095 PROTO=TCP SPT=220 DPT=6129 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 >SYN URGP=0
```

My code is this at the moment:

```
#!//usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os
import re
from collections import defaultdict

    tipos={}
    p= re.compile ('bridge kernel:.*:')
    with open (sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            match = p.search(line)
            if match:
                taux=(line.split(":") [3])
                tipos[taux]=1
    print (tipos)
```

The code doesn't give an error, but all key have the save value.

I've read about `defaultdict` and `Counters` but couldn't make them work.

Help me, please.

Comment: are all the values equal to 1?

Comment: Maybe you mean `ipos[taux] += 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the version of your code, you never increase the number of counts of taux in tipos, so they should all be one. And yes, defaultdicts will help, since they automatically instantiate missing dictionary entries with the type you pass in. The general defaultdict counting pattern is as follows:

```
a = defaultdict(int)
a['asdf'] += 1
# a['asdf'] will now be 1, since it updates from 0
```

EDIT: Including @Jean-FrançoisFabre comment, I want to point out that the `collections` module comes with an object specifically designed to count anything hashable - Counter. From the looks of things, it relies on much of the same backend, so performance should be similar, but it comes with some nice little extras (like the `most_common(number_of_most_common_elements)` method. This can be used like a defaultdict, but without the dedicated `(int)` argument:

```
a = Counter()
a['asdf'] += 1
# a['asdf'] will now be 1, since it updates from 0
```

In general, each argument passed will correspond to a default value. That means that you could do the following as well:

```
a = defaultdict(int)
print(a['asdf'])  # will print 0
a = defaultdict(float)
print(a['asdf'])  # will print 0.0
a = defaultdict(list)
print(a['asdf'])  # will print [], and is particularly useful if you want a dict of lists, since you don't need to check whether your key already exists in the dict
```

as for your code, this means that you want:

```
tipos=defaultdict(int)
p= re.compile ('bridge kernel:.*:')
with open (sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = p.search(line)
        if match:
            taux=(line.split(":") [3])
            tipos[taux]+=1
print (tipos)
```

Comment: `collections.Counter` is even better to count elements.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks - good pointer. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a defaultdict:

```
tipos = defaultdict(int)
p= re.compile ('bridge kernel:.*:')
with open (sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = p.search(line)
        if match:
            taux=(line.split(":") [3])
            tipos[taux] += 1
print (tipos)
```

You have it imported there but you didn't use it